# Bad microsecond resolution in Python

Tags: python, datetime, time

When using python datetime.now() I only get a resolution close to the millisecond. I need a microsecond resolution for network purposes, or at least being able to mesure the time elapsed between two received packets at a microsecond resolution.

Here is an example of the resolution I get:

```
from datetime import  datetime
for i in range(10):
    print(datetime.now().microsecond)
```

it returns :

```
224000
239000
247000
255000
264000
272000
284000
295000
308000
319000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the right clock for your platform; use [`timeit.default_timer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.default_timer).

`datetime` uses the same C API used by `time.time()`, which on Windows doesn't offer as much granularity as `time.clock()` offers. `timeit.default_timer` points to the right version for your platform to offer the best choice.

Comment: Forward compatibility pitfall: In Python 3.3, `timeit.default_timer = time.perf_counter`, which is useful for benchmarking but possibly not for network stuff: Undefined reference point and documented to measure "a short duration".